# Android: A webview with a single element

Tags: android, webview, element

How do I do a webview to show a single element?

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        wv.loadUrl("http://exampleurl.com/");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
                    builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('header').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
                    builder.append("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('pile');");
                    view.loadUrl(builder.toString());
                }
    });
    }
```

This is an image example to my question:

[image: image question]

Best Regards!!

Answer (score 0):

I could archive 100% width for pile but not height, but that's probably because I don't know css very well. Sorry for not giving an complete answer.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //hide stuff you dont want to see
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('pilu').style.display = 'none';"); 
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('pilo').style.display = 'none';");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('pila').style.display = 'none';");

    //style div to fit screen
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('pile').setAttribute('style','width:100%;height:100%;');");
}
```